# Getting ClassCastException, java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to org.springframework.amqp.core.Message:

Tags: spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I am using spring-amqp, and using consumerBatchEnabled to receive batch of events as mentioned in below link:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.2.5.RELEASE/reference/html/#receiving-batch

and registering the listener as below:

```
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;

@RabbitListener(queues = "batch.2", containerFactory = "consumerBatchContainerFactory")
public void consumerBatch2(List<org.springframework.messaging.Message<Invoice>> messages) {
    //code here to process events
}
```

Also have config class defined as below

```
    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory factory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory){);
        RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
        rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(messageConverter());
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory consumerBatchContainerFactory(
            SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
            ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.MANUAL);
        factory.setPrefetchCount(1000);
        factory.setBatchListener(true);
        factory.setBatchSize(1000);
        factory.setConsumerBatchEnabled(true);
        factory.setReceiveTimeout(1000l);
        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter messageConverter(){
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }
```

however when I publish the event, i get ClassCastException, java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to org.springframework.amqp.core.Message:

stack trace

```
Execution of Rabbit message listener failed.","logger_name":"org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler","thread_name":"org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#0-1","level":"WARN","level_value":30000,"stack_trace":"java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to org.springframework.amqp.core.Message\n\tat brave.spring.rabbit.TracingRabbitListenerAdvice.invoke(TracingRabbitListenerAdvice.java:75)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)\n\tat org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.$Proxy210.invokeListener(Unknown Source)\n\tat org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1537)\n\tat org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1532)\n\tat org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1472)\n\tat org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.executeWithList(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1037)\n\tat org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1026)\n\tat org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:923)\n\tat org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1600(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:83)\n\tat org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.mainLoop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1298)\n\tat org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1204)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\n"}
{"timestamp":"2021-06-10T13:47:56.851+0000","message":"Restarting Consumer
```

There is no issue without consumerBatchEnabled, and able to receive and process Message

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "batch.2")
public void consumerBatch2(org.springframework.messaging.Message<Invoice> message) {
   //code here
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its a known issue https://github.com/openzipkin/brave/issues/1240.
Bug is resolved in library version 5.12.4